# `wc -l` alternative that displays the count, as it receives the lines

Tags: shell, performance, io, wc

I'm using `wc -l` to count the lines in output of a command, as the input is piped to it.

```
commad | wc -l
```

This works fine, but if `command` is doing some heavy computation, this is quite slow. Is there an alternative which displays the count of lines which have been "piped in so far"?

Such a thing would especially be useful when I'm doing a sort of per-item computation, like

```
cat something | xargs -L1 heavy-per-line-computation | wc -l
```

One way I could do this manually is to pipe the output to a file (`command > file`) and periodically do `cat file | wc -l` on it. But a single command (which doesn't redirect to files, to avoid wasteful I/O), is what I'm after.

Comment: can you know how many lines there are in total beforehand?

Comment: What is the purpose of getting `the count of lines which have been piped in so far?`. Is it to track the progress of the operation?

Comment: @gogoud, nope. That'd also defeat the purpose of using `wc -l`

Comment: @PauloTomé not necessarily. I know a tool (gnu `parallel`) which is capable of tracking progress. But if the computation itself is producing multiple lines which I want to count, then it's useless and I have to resort to `wc -l`

Comment: The `cat` can probably go, just use the `xargs` and pipe to `wc`. also you might have a buffering issue?

Comment: @LinuxSecurityFreak the requirement is generic, hence `command` too. The solution should be such that what `command` is doesn't matter, and that is exactly the case with the current answers.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
awk '{print NR}'
```

This command prints a new number for each line encountered. If the final line is complete then the last number will agree with what `wc -l` would say. If the final line is [incomplete](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap03.html#tag_03_195) then `awk` may count it (in my Kubuntu GNU `awk` does) but `wc -l` would not (because it really counts newlines); so there may be discrepancy.

Another discrepancy is if the input is completely empty: `wc -l` will print `0`, our `awk` will print nothing. To make it print `0` use this variant:

```
awk '{print NR} END {if (NR==0) print NR}'
```

Or maybe you want each new number overwrite the old one in the same line of your console. Then this:

```
awk '{printf "\r%s",NR} END {print "\r"NR}'
```

Example: `yes | head -n 76543 | awk '{printf "\r%s",NR} END {print "\r"NR}'`

Note the command consumes its input (`tee` may be handy). For monitoring purpose you may be interested in:

```
awk '{print NR OFS $0}'
```

which (with the default `OFS` being space) is almost like `cat -n` (if your `cat` supports `-n`).

---

`pv -l` counts lines and it can be used inside a pipeline. Example:

```
for i in 1 2 3 4 5; do date; sleep 1; done | pv -l | wc -l
```

Consider `pv -lb` for quite minimal output.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, thanks! `pv` seems to be purpose-built for exactly this.

Comment: Linux Mint seems to lack `pv`

Answer (score 2):

Here's a solution using Ruby.

`count_lines` prints (via `stderr`) at most every half a second the count of lines received so far, and the total count at the end (via `stdout`).

```bsh
read -d '' make_lines <<'EOF'
  STDOUT.sync = true
  [0.2, 0.1, 0.5, 0.1, 0.6, 0.1, 0.3, 0.1, 0.3, 0.01, 0.01].each do |t|
    puts
    sleep t
  end
EOF

read -d '' count_lines <<'EOF'
  lines = 0
  t = 0
  while gets do
    lines += 1
    now = Time.now.to_f
    if now - t > 0.5
      warn lines
      t = now
    end
  end
  puts lines
EOF

ruby -e "$make_lines" | ruby -e "$count_lines"
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you are looking for `pv` (Pipe view):

```
seq 100000000000 | pv -l | wc -l
```

Answer (score 0):

Most terminals take `CR (\r)` to be "Move to column 1". This allows you to keep over-writing the previous output.

This is a script `dwc` that will read from stdin (which could be a `tail -f` from a file, or from an output process substitution). There is a sample test-bed in the script.

It takes a `-l` option. The default is to print the input line number to the current row in the terminal, as six numeric digits. With `-l`, it also prints the first 60 chars of the last line received, clearing any previous text. When it sees EOF, it emits newline so the prompt appears under the last output.

```
#! /bin/bash

#.. dwc [-l]

AWK_SHORT='
BEGIN { Fmt = "\r%6d "; }
{ printf (Fmt, NR); }
END { printf ("\n"); }
'

AWK_LONG='
BEGIN { Fmt = "\r%6d  %.60s"; Clr = sprintf ("%60s", ""); }
{ printf (Fmt, NR, $0 Clr); }
END { printf ("\n"); }
'
    if [[ "${1}" = "-l" ]]; then
        awk "${AWK_LONG}"
    else
        awk "${AWK_SHORT}"
    fi

    exit

    #.. Test method.
    man ls | head -n 40 |
         while IFS='' read X; do
             printf '%s\n' "${X}"; sleep 0.75
         done |
         tee >( ./dwc -l ) > foo.txt
```